# How to compare directory/files and permissions on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Is there a tool or command which will compare two directory trees on separate computers and output a list of differences, including differences in permissions?

I was looking at http://winmerge.org/ and it didn't seem to have this feature (it seems to compares file sizes and contents, but not attributes).  Took a look through the options, but didn't see a setting to change this.

I've had some problems in the past with permissions getting messed up on some driver directories after an update and it would nice to compare a working installation with a broken one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you throught about using PowerShell to do this?

PS2 includes a cmdlet [`Get-ACL`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl) which enums the NFTS permissions (including owner) for a given folder/file.

Comment: Yes, I did think about Powershell - but had hoped not to use it.  I don't use it often enough to get comfortable with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ICACLs.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc753525.aspx), [Included since Vista or so](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919240) to dump the permissions to a text file.  Then use WinDiff or Beyond Compare, or whatever your favorite file comparison tool is, to see the differences.

Example icacls command line:

```
icacls C:\Folder1 /T > Folder1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't find anything that will perform a "diff" on file permissions in Windows, but I do know that RoboCopy and Richcopy (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog) will copy files while preserving NTFS attributes like permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend `setacl`. It is a free tool you can obtain from [helgeklein.com](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/).

To compare two directories I did this:

- Make a list of all ACLs in both folders
- List in a text format by:

  ```sh
  setacl -ot file -on FolderA -actn list -lst "f:tab" > AclsFolderA.txt  
  setacl -ot file -on FolderB -actn list -lst "f:tab" > AclsFolderB.txt
  ```
- Compare the 2 lists. I do this with `diff` from CygWin:

  ```sh
  diff AclsFolderA.txt AclsFolderB.txt
  ```

I had a problem with comparing two user folders. These folders needed to have identical ACLs except for the user who *owned* the folder.
I solved this by replace the username in the ACL with a common name *customer*. This allowed me to compare the ACL without having an obvious difference on the username itself.

Comment: You could also use the dos command "COMP" to compare.

Answer (score 0):

## Try dedicated tools

Probably it worthwile to look at:

- [CJWDEV NTFS Permission Reporter](http://cjwdev.co.uk/Software/NtfsReports/Info.html) or
- [Scooter Soft Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php)

Notes:

- 1st one can scan folder tree & produce permission report which can be saved in Excel (having 2 reports you can do comparison in Excel),
- 2nd can copy permissions...

Unfortunately these 2 are not free, and not do exactly what you want but may be helpful for your task...

AFAIK there are no off-the-shelf tool which can easily & conveniently do NTFS permissions comparison/copy, despite existing demand :)